# How to measure isolation resistance between floating ground levels?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ground-loop, isolated

There a two isolated ground pins on an isolated dc-dc converter
  [image: e.g. Murata, Dual Output BWR Models].

What method is used for measuring isolation resistance between input side ground level and floating (output side) ground level?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to characterize the isolation between input and output grounds, you could use a specialized insulation meter such as The Fluke 1550C.

Comment: Thx @Dmitri S: Means it mostly is characterization of the isolating component (e.g. transformer, capacitor, switched coil) considering leaking/transferred voltage and current ripples instead of (demand profile dependent) constant resistance number? I don't understand how this isolation between these ground levels is to be described, so measuring could be one mean of understanding that better, but further explanation would help also. Maybe isolation resistance is wrong wording?